# Как я могу красиво проверить первые символы в строке?

Tags: python, строки

Итак у меня есть команда которую я ввожу допустим `/dosmth -a -b -c file.txt`. Я хочу проверять только первые символы строки. У меня есть словарь со строками и значениями к ним, если эта строка в начале команды. find проверяет всю строку, слайсы со сравнениями выглядят немного колхозно. Вот что я хочу в коде:

```
commands = ["/all": 23, "/dd pc": 19, "/clear": 199, "/dosmth": 1]

command = "/dosmth -a -b smth.txt"

def checkCommand(command:str, commands:dict) -> int:
    ???
    return commandNumber


result = checkCommand(command, commands) # returns 1
```

Comment: `.spilt()[0]` даст первое слово в строке

Comment: Да, но в примере я показал, что команда может быть с пробелом. И еще сплит делит прям всю строку, а мне нужно ее проверять каждый раз когда я ввожу 1 символ (не оптимизировано)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У класса `str` для такого случая есть функция `startswith(prefix, start, end)`.

- `prefix` - строка или кортеж строк, наличие которых в начале этой строки нужно проверить
- `start` - индекс начала, откуда следует начать поиск
- `end` - индекс конца, где следует поиск закончить

Сама функция возвращает булево значение (т.е. `True` или `False`)

Comment: это не очень хорошо, вполне может быть что несколько команд начинаются одинаково, например `àll` и `allusers`

Comment: Ну тут уже разработчик сам должен решать, как ему лучше